# socket.io broadcast in a room

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io to broadcast only to users of a specific room (in another word, to send to all users in that room except me, the sender). So far, I have tried:

```
io.of("/").in(room_temp).broadcast.emit('transcription', data);
io.of("/").to(room_temp).broadcast.emit('transcription', data);
io.of("/").broadcast.in(room_temp).emit('transcription', data);
io.of("/").broadcast.to(room_temp).emit('transcription', data);
```

None of them work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`io.of("/").to(room_temp).emit('transcription', data);` would submit to everyone in the room include the user itself.

`socket.to(room_temp).emit('transcription', data);` would submit to everyone in the room except yourself.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/):

When you want to send something to all users of a room, use

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

When you want to send something to all users of a room except for one `socket` in that room (which is usually called "broadcasting"), use

```
socket.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

Comment: I have tried `socket.to('some room').emit('some event');`, but I think it emits to myself as well.

Comment: I have used the minimal example on the documentation page and wrote
 
`io.on("connection", (socket) => {socket.join("room"); socket.to("room").emit("message", "someone joined the the room");});`

And in fact, the socket does NOT get that message! So there must be something wrong with your other code.